# Smart pointer with small object optimization

Tags: c++

I have a hierarchy of classes. The base class have a virtual destructor and some virtual methods. Most of derived classes have no members at all. Some derived classes have POD-only members.

Since most of these classes have no members, it feels like a waste of resources creating them on heap and passing `unique_ptr`s around.

I'd like to use a smart pointer which can perform small object optimization. That pointer shall store all objects that match the following conditions in a special buffer without allocating new memory:

1. class only consist of vtable pointer and members that are trivially moveable;
2. class have no user-defined move operator;
3. class is small enough.

I have two questions about how to implement this.

First, how to detect such class? It's not trivially moveable because there are virtual functions.

Second, is it safe to memcpy such class?

An additional question: are there any known implementations of such classes?

Comment: There is [`std::is_trivial`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_trivial), [`std::is_trivially_copyable`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_trivially_copyable) and [`std::is_pod`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_pod) (though the last one is deprecated in c++20). I'm not sure which one you are looking for, but you can see all the type traits available in [`<type_trait>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/type_traits).

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux problem is, there are virtual functions in my base class so neither of triviality check is positive.

Comment: Then `memcpy` will be unspecified for your types. It's not safe to copy them (at least in the general sense).

Comment: Your class probably need a *placement clone*.

Comment: I'm getting an XY smell off this question. If the class is truly simple enough, both its copy constructor and move constructor will be cheap-as-memcpy. And when they're not that cheap, it's because memcpy wouldn't work either. Why is there this assumption that `memcpy` which must deal with non-aligned, odd-sized data is faster than a specialized copy operation which maps naturally to CPU load/store operations?

Comment: Because we don't know the exact type of a stored object. So we have to either store a pointer to a function which performs copying or do a virtual call.

Comment: I don't think you should bother checking the first two constraints. You just to constrain on size and move into a placement `new`ed location

Comment: "it feels like a waste of resources" is probably not a good-enough reason to optimize, on its own.  Before trying to fix anything, you should first come up with an objective test to measure your program's performance, so that if you decide to change the design, you can later verify that the new design actually improved measured efficiency enough to make the added complexity worth keeping.  (and then, if you're convinced that the problem exists to the extent that it is worth solving, you might look into use a slab-allocator/object-pool approach instead; or just pass small objects by-value)

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure whether this is strictly legal according to the standard, but I would have thought it's a pretty portable way to detect whether a class is polymorphic and dataless:

```
#include <type_traits>

namespace detail
{
    struct BaselinePoly
    {
        virtual ~BaselinePoly();
    };
}

template<class T>
struct IsDatalessPolymorphic
: std::integral_constant
  <
    bool, 
    std::is_polymorphic<T>::value && sizeof(T) == sizeof(detail::BaselinePoly)
  > 
{
};

struct Foo
{
    virtual ~Foo();
};

struct Bar : Foo {};
struct Baz : Foo { int x; };

int main()
{
    static_assert(IsDatalessPolymorphic<Bar>());
    static_assert(!IsDatalessPolymorphic<Baz>());
}
```

The implicit move and copy operators ought to be extremely trivial. I suspect you'll gain nothing from `memcpy` trickery.